# Graph not rendering correct scale with NVD3

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I haven't been able to make the line chart render with a correct scale and the documentation is practically non existent for nvd3. It renders ok if I only use the first set of values (with the key Success).

I have a sample demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LBqk3/1/

And the code / attached sample data:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Requests')
        .tickFormat(function (d) {
        return d3.time.format('%d %b')(new Date(d));
    });

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([400, 400]);

    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Amount')
        .scale(y)
        .tickFormat(d3.format('.2f'));

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum([{
        "values": [{
            "x": 1387893600000,
            "y": "170"
        }, {
            "x": 1387980000000,
            "y": "416"
        }, {
            "x": 1388066400000,
            "y": "743"
        }, {
            "x": 1388152800000,
            "y": "633"
        }, {
            "x": 1388239200000,
            "y": "500"
        }, {
            "x": 1388325600000,
            "y": "604"
        }, {
            "x": 1388412000000,
            "y": "683"
        }, {
            "x": 1388498400000,
            "y": "485"
        }, {
            "x": 1388584800000,
            "y": "509"
        }, {
            "x": 1388671200000,
            "y": "677"
        }, {
            "x": 1388757600000,
            "y": "610"
        }, {
            "x": 1388844000000,
            "y": "607"
        }, {
            "x": 1388930400000,
            "y": "538"
        }, {
            "x": 1389016800000,
            "y": "596"
        }, {
            "x": 1389103200000,
            "y": "609"
        }, {
            "x": 1389189600000,
            "y": "581"
        }, {
            "x": 1389276000000,
            "y": "503"
        }, {
            "x": 1389362400000,
            "y": "524"
        }, {
            "x": 1389448800000,
            "y": "515"
        }, {
            "x": 1389535200000,
            "y": "580"
        }, {
            "x": 1389621600000,
            "y": "592"
        }, {
            "x": 1389708000000,
            "y": "573"
        }, {
            "x": 1389794400000,
            "y": "597"
        }, {
            "x": 1389880800000,
            "y": "717"
        }, {
            "x": 1389967200000,
            "y": "2760"
        }],
        "key": "Missed"
    }])
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Comment: It looks like your y values are strings and not numbers. Is that your intention?

Comment: You're correct, I just figured out that was the problem and it's now fixed. Didn't even realize it in my dataset at first

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your y values are strings and you're treating them like numbers. Replacing

```
"y": "604"
```

with

```
"y": 604
```

and so on for all values should fix the issue.